# Which file format uses less memory in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv, file, export-to-csv

I wrote the code for points generation which will generate a dataframe for every one second and it keeps on generating. Each dataframe has 1000 rows and 7 columns.. It was implemented using while loop and thus for every iteration one dataframe is generated and it must be appended on a file. While file format should I use to manage the memory efficiency? Which file format takes less memory.? Can anyone give me a suggestion.. Is it okay to use csv? If so what datatype should I prefer to use.. Currently my dataframe has int16 values.. Should I append the same  or should I convert it into binary format or byte format?

Comment: just try some and see which is more efficient for your use case! further, there are choices to be made about loading the data back too .. if you're worried about memory, you may find operating on only part of the file at once is important

Comment: do you mean `RAM memory` or `space on disk`? If you only generate and write then it should use the same size of `RAM` but more and more `DISK`. Using binary format or compressed could use less DISK but it could be simpler to work with CSV - it may append data without loadind previous content.

Comment: @furas RAM MEMORY.. After appending.. I should use config file to load certain portion of file into a text file..

Comment: Each iteration creates a new 1000x7 dataframe? And that's a pandas dataframe?

Comment: @tdelaney yup. It keeps on generating pandas dataframe of shape 1000x7 for each iteration and it keeps on generating.. The thing is to collect all those dataframes and store it in a. File.. Which file format and datatype takes less memory to store as it was a replica of real time application.

Comment: I wrote a demo for fixed size data types, but pandas uses several different formats. You may be interested in parquet or bigtable for example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`numpy` arrays can be stored in binary format. Since you you have a single `int16` data type, you can create a numpy array and write that. You would have 2 bytes per int16 value which is fairly good for size. The trick is that you need to know the dimensions of the stored data when you read it later. In this example its hard coded. This is a bit fragile - if you change your mind and start using different dimensions later, old data would have to be converted.

Assuming you want to read a bunch of 1000x7 dataframes later, you could do something like the example below. The writer keeps appending 1000x7 int16s and the reader chunks them back into dataframes. If you don't use anything specific to pandas itself, you would be better off just sticking with numpy for all of your operations and skip the demonstrated conversions.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

def write_df(filename, df):
    with open(filename, "ab") as fp:
        np.array(df, dtype="int16").tofile(fp)

def read_dfs(filename, dim=(1000,7)):
    """Sequentially reads dataframes from a file formatted as raw int16
    with dimension 1000x7"""
    size = dim[0] * dim[1]
    with open(filename, "rb") as fp:
        while True:
            arr = np.fromfile(fp, dtype="int16", count=size)
            if not len(arr):
                break
            yield pd.DataFrame(arr.reshape(*dim))

import os

# ready for test
test_filename = "test123"
if os.path.exists(test_filename):
    os.remove(test_filename)
    
df = pd.DataFrame({"a":[1,2,3], "b":[4,5,6]})

# write test file
for _ in range(5):
    write_df(test_filename, df)
    
# read and verify test file
return_data = [df for df in read_dfs(test_filename, dim=(3,2))]
assert len(return_data) == 5
```